# PDO dblib nextRowset not working

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, centos, freetds

I'm in the process of converting a PHP application from running in a Windows environment to a Linux based environment.

It utilises PDO to run Stored Procedures against a Microsoft SQL Server database.

So, I've installed and configured PHP 5.6.22, Apache, freetds and pdo dblib to facilitate the application.

Most stored procedure executions are working perfectly. Except ones that return multiple rowsets.

When I call `$pdo->nextRowset()`, I get this fatal error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: PDO_DBLIB: dbresults() returned FAIL
```

The only reference I can find to this was a bug reported in PHP 5.6.9 that was fixed.

However, I am getting the same issue in PHP 5.6.22.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening and how I can resolve it?

Comment: Can you return a more detailed error than fail by tweaking whatever that setting in `php.ini` for error verbosity is (sorry, haven't touched PHP in years or I'd be more specific). If we can get the actual FreeTDS error to bubble to the surface, that'd be much easier to diagnose, since you're likely swapping out the SQL Server driver on Windows for FreeTDS on Linux.

Comment: PHP is on highest verbosity and only shows the error message in my question.

Comment: Just checking, did you run the procedure through a fetchall?

Comment: @Ctc I just use `fetch()` for each rowset since it only returns 1 row per rowset.

Comment: @Jamesking56 could you please post the code which executes and fetches the results.

Comment: Are you sure that returning multiple rowsets is necessary? Maybe it could be much simpler to split code returning multiple rowsets into smaller pieces and call them separately.

Comment: @Jamesking56 did you try my answer ? I resolved with that "work-around"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you fetching data with `PDO::fetch` or `PDO::fetchAll` ? Because if you use the "fetch" method and don't reach the end of the rows `PDO::nextRowset()` will fail (I don't know why, it just happened to me).

So, for me works to **force to scan all rows** **until `PDO::fetch` returns false**, then `PDO::nextRowset()` will execute normally.

It means that if you have only one row in a rowset you must call `PDO::fetch` at least two time (1 for retrieve data and 1 to return false) and then pass to next rowset.

Comment: It would be nice if this rubbish behavior was documented somewhere, like on the manual page for PDO::nextRowset().

Comment: Yeah, it would be really nice ... I spent hours on this behavior until I found this "issue" (or feature ..)

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with `PDO::nextRowset()`, as it returns true even there is no more rowsets available, therefore when calling `fetchAll()`, it raises exception `HY000`.

you can follow a simple trick by checking number of columns with method
`PDO::columnCount()` before fetching rowset. If it is non-zero, you have a valid rowset, and thus you could call `PDO::fetchAll()`.

Even if `PDO::nextRowset()` reports true, `columnCount()` will report number of columns before moving to next rowset.

```
while ($pdo->columnCount()) {
    $data[] = $pdo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //or, $pdo->fetchAll() 
    $pdo->nextRowset();
}
```

**Also, it is recommended to make all PDO operations within the try block, otherwise you may get unhandled exceptions.**